# JavaFX 8 default message icons

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

with the last few updates of JavaFX we have alerts. I want to get the message's default icons (error, warning, ...). In Swing, I can get the L&F message icons through some `UIManager`'s properties. How can I get the message's default icons in JavaFX? Are them contained in properties, or defined by CSS class?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are defined in `modena.css` as

```
.alert.confirmation.dialog-pane,
.text-input-dialog.dialog-pane,
.choice-dialog.dialog-pane {
    -fx-graphic: url("dialog-confirm.png");
}

.alert.information.dialog-pane {
    -fx-graphic: url("dialog-information.png");
}

.alert.error.dialog-pane {
    -fx-graphic: url("dialog-error.png");
}

.alert.warning.dialog-pane {
    -fx-graphic: url("dialog-warning.png");
}
```

You can override them in a regular way.

Comment: Example source: https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dialog-pane{
    -fx-graphic: url(the url of your icon) ;
}
```

To hide definitely the icon, put

```css
-fx-graphic: null;
```